# Elegant way to modify <key>\.code for shadows color

Tags: tikz-pgf, shadows, pgf-blur

Trying to add color for shadows with `shadows.blur` library, I have method which consist of modify  the code of `render blur shadow`, here a MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{render blur shadow/.code=
{\pgfbs@savebb
\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\pgfbs@input@path}%
\pgfbs@compute@shadow@bbox
\pgfbs@process@rounding{\pgfbs@input@path}{\pgfbs@fadepath}%
\pgfbs@apply@canvas@transform
\colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!violet}%
\pgfdeclarefading{shadowfading}{\pgfbs@paint@fading}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{violet}%
\pgfsetfading{shadowfading}%
{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfbs@midx}{\pgfbs@midy}}}%
\pgfbs@usebbox{fill}%
\pgfbs@restorebb
},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=white, draw=black, blur shadow,font=\Large] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original definition of `render blur shadow` is

```
render blur shadow/.code=
    {\pgfbs@savebb
    \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\pgfbs@input@path}%
    \pgfbs@compute@shadow@bbox
    \pgfbs@process@rounding{\pgfbs@input@path}{\pgfbs@fadepath}%
    \pgfbs@apply@canvas@transform
    \colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!black}%
    \pgfdeclarefading{shadowfading}{\pgfbs@paint@fading}%
    \pgfsetfillcolor{black}%
    \pgfsetfading{shadowfading}%
    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfbs@midx}{\pgfbs@midy}}}%
    \pgfbs@usebbox{fill}%
    \pgfbs@restorebb
    }
```

From the above code I just want to change `black` to `violet` with a simple manner, I tried to use

```
render blur shadow/.append code=
{\colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!violet}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{violet}%
},
```

But this does not succeed, any suggestions.

**Update**

I meant if there is a macro like `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` to change code of 
`render blur shadow` like this without rewriting code of `render blur command`

```
\patchcmd{render blur command}{black}{violet}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

**Desirable code**

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\patchcmd{render blur command}{black}{violet}{<success>}{<failure>}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=white, draw=black, blur shadow,font=\Large] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, the problem is that the shadow is ugly? Sorry, I'm not sure I understood. :D

Comment: My MWE work perfectly, I want a short method to change `render blur shadow` without rewrite the entire code

Comment: Replace `black` with `#1` and use `render blur shadow=violet` which might need to modify the `blur shadow` too

Comment: @percusse That gives an error, though (which was unexpected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply replace `black` with `violet` "locally" like this :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    render blur shadow/.prefix code={
      \colorlet{black}{violet}
    }
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=white, draw=black, blur shadow,font=\Large] {Node};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]