# Apply multiple fadings to drawing in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Original question title - "Fade from specific point using fadings TikZ"

How can I fade out from a specific point on an object? I want to apply two fadings to this red square. Consider this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw [black] (4,0)--(4,5);
\draw [black] (1,0)--(1,5);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (4,-0.3)--(5,-0.3);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (1,-0.3)--(0,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to fade out to 100% transparency, but only starting at the black lines and then out to left and right edges (as indicated by the arrows).

For this simple example, I can achieve the effect I'm looking for by re-drawing this diagram as three separate rectangles. Keeping the centre rectangle solid `red`, and applying `path fading=west` and `path fading=east` to the left and right rectangles respectively. But this doesn't seem very elegant. And is not practical for a more complicated shape I am working on.

**What I want to achieve**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [red,path fading=west] (0,0) rectangle (1,5);
\fill [red] (1,0) rectangle (4,5);
\fill [red,path fading=east] (4,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw [black] (4,0)--(4,5);
\draw [black] (1,0)--(1,5);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (4,-0.3)--(5,-0.3);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (1,-0.3)--(0,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

**UPDATE**
The reason the 'splitting up' method doesn't work for me is because I have more complicated elements of my `tikzpicture`. Consider having an image overlaid on the red square. How can the fading also apply to it?

[image]

Perhaps the `fadings` package is not what I'm after...?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\node at (2.5,2.5) (Image)  {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image.pdf}};
\draw [black] (4,0)--(4,5);
\draw [black] (1,0)--(1,5);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (4,-0.3)--(5,-0.3);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (1,-0.3)--(0,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The title of this question doesn't reflect its content very well, as far as I can tell. Either that or I, too, have misunderstood what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can get some partial answer using the `shadows.blur` package and modifying it a bit. I am using this because it already comes with the facilities to draw contours around a given shape in different steps. What one has to do is to adjust the shadow color. This has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328561/121799), but unfortunately I was unable to make the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328561/121799) work for this purpose as, according to what I find, it mocks up the steps (but I might well be doing something stupid). Yet it is not at all difficult to re-adjust the color in a Ti*k*Zy way. I illustrate this by fading out a cloud because that is a fairly complicated shape, and I like the idea of making a cloud more cloudy, yet this trick can be used for general shapes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,shadows.blur,shapes}
% \tikzset{ % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328561/121799
%     render blur shadow/.prefix code={
%       \colorlet{black}{orange}
%     }
%   } % does not work, unfortunately
\makeatletter
\tikzset{ % based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328433/121799
/tikz/render blur shadow/.code={
    \pgfbs@savebb
    \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\pgfbs@input@path}%
    \pgfbs@compute@shadow@bbox
    \pgfbs@process@rounding{\pgfbs@input@path}{\pgfbs@fadepath}%
    \pgfbs@apply@canvas@transform
    \colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!\my@shadow@color}%
    \pgfdeclarefading{shadowfading}{\pgfbs@paint@fading}%
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\my@shadow@color}%
    \pgfsetfading{shadowfading}%
       {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfbs@midx}{\pgfbs@midy}}}%
    \pgfbs@usebbox{fill}%
    \pgfbs@restorebb
  },}
\tikzset{
  /tikz/shadow color/.store in=\my@shadow@color,
  /tikz/shadow color=gray,
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  cloudy/.style={cloud,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, aspect=2}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every shadow/.style={shadow blur steps=20,
  shadow scale=1.2,shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=0pt,shadow opacity=100}]
    \node[cloudy,fill=orange,blur shadow={shadow color=orange}] at (0,0) {I'm a cloud};

    \node[fill=red,blur shadow={shadow color=red,shadow scale=1.25},minimum width=4cm,minimum
    height=4cm] at (0,6){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Answer to edited question: Very simple, just add a white fading rectangle on top.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\node at (2.5,2.5) (Image)  {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image.pdf}};
\fill [white,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (1,5);
\fill [white,path fading=west] (4,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw [black] (4,0)--(4,5);
\draw [black] (1,0)--(1,5);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (4,-0.3)--(5,-0.3);
\draw [->,line width=1mm] (1,-0.3)--(0,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Myles Well, you can always use clip, right? Just add `\clip (-3,3.7) rectangle (3,8.3);` before the red node.

Comment: I've added an update to my question. It was perhaps not clear what I was after. It was not exactly a more complex shape, but a diagram with more elements to it. I want the fade to apply to everything in the diagram.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a `scope fading` if you want to fade a node e.g. to include an external image. At least, so says the Ti*k*Z manual. Since your fading is not just one of the standard ones, but a bit more complex, you might want to use a picture as the basis for the fading and then apply the fading as a `scope fading`.

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=my fading]
  \fill [transparent!0] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
  \shade [left color=transparent!100, right color=transparent!0] (-3,-2) rectangle (-2,2);
  \shade [left color=transparent!0, right color=transparent!100] (2,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \path [scope fading=my fading, fit fading=false] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
    \fill [color=blue] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
    \node {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: faded node and stuff]

Comment: Excellent this does work, I did not find in the manual that I have, what I want to know is if it must necessarily be centered at the origin, since in my code I had to do it because it did not work for me.

Comment: @JLeonV. I'm not sure exactly what you mean. You can always shift the fading, just as you can rotate it. But, since you're doing it with a picture anyway, I guess you wouldn't need to do that. (Fadings from pictures never work quite as intuitively as the out-of-the-box ones - at least, not with my intuitions!)